# Add domain user and group to local administrators

Tags: vbscript

I have a piece of VBS code that I have modified that basically adds a specified domain user and group to the PCs local Administrators group. It works fine on Windows 7, but not at all on Windows 8.

```
Call AddUserToGroup("./Administrators", "myDomain.net/NetworkAdminis")
Call AddUserToGroup("./Administrators", "myDomain.net/Domain Admins")
Call addDomainUser("myDomain", "myUserGroup")

Sub AddUserToGroup(local, domain)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim objLocalGroup
    Dim objDomainGroup
    Dim server

    For Each server in servers
        Set objLocalGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & local & ",group")
        Set objDomainGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & domain & ",group")
        With objLocalGroup
            .Add(objDomainGroup.AdsPath)
            .SetInfo
        End With            
    Next

    Set objLocalGroup = Nothing
    Set objDomainGroup = Nothing
End Sub

Sub addDomainUser(strDomain, strUser)
    Dim strComputer
    Dim objWshNet
    Dim objGroup
    Dim objUser

    Set objWshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    strComputer = objWshNet.ComputerName
    Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrators,group")
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomain & "/" & strUser & ",user")
    If Not objGroup.IsMember(objUser.ADsPath) Then
        objGroup.Add (objUser.ADsPath)
    End If

    Set objWshNet = Nothing
    Set objGroup = Nothing
    Set objUser = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have debugged the code line by line using VBA's IDE and there seems to be no error condition firing. It executes all lines, but it is not adding the users and groups as it did with Windows 7 and below. The script is being run as local administrator.

Comment: What the **not works** stands for? Change `On Error Resume Next` to `On Error GoTo 0` to see error(s); then [edit] your question and add more info, please.

Comment: The code above produces no errors.

Comment: Even if you remove the line `On Error Resume Next`? Are you running the script "as administrator"? Also, why are you using a script instead of [Group Policy Restricted Groups](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/279301) in the first place?

Comment: Removing `On Error Resume Next` doesn't have any effect.Like I said, I ran the code using Words VBA IDE and it doesn't go to error condition. I am using the VBS to run in a group policy, because depending if it is a server or not it will adda  particular set of users and groups, among other things. The script is being run as a local administrator.